# Mapping a union of objects to another union of objects with a generic using `Extract`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have `Multi`, a type consisting of a union of objects:

```js
interface MultiA {
    type: 'multi-a',
}
interface MultiB {
    type: 'multi-b',
}
type Multi = MultiA | MultiB;
```

And I have another type `Ext`, consisting of a union of objects that extend upon the first ones in different ways:

```js
interface ExtA extends MultiA {
    foo: string
}
interface ExtB extends MultiB {
    bar: string
}
type Ext = ExtA | ExtB;
```

I want to map a value of type `Multi` to `Ext` while adding the values required by `ExtA` or `ExtB`.
Example:

```js
function mapTypes<K extends Multi['type']>(
    val: Extract<Multi, { type: K }>
): Extract<Ext, { type: K }> {
    if (val.type === 'multi-a') {
        return {
            ...val,
            foo: '',
        }
    } else {
        return {
            ...val,
            bar: '',
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the `Extract<Multi, { type: K }` to map to the return type `Extract<Ext, { type: K }>` without problems since `K` is the same.

However, as part of the error message shows ([Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIFcA2ZgEFkDeAUMqcmAJ4AOEAXMgOQC2WOAtHAwDREC+RoSLEQoM2YACFCJMpRr1mrYGwBG3PkTmilyALxol+AD4HxEgNxEB4aPCTIAogA8w+CC4ggAJgGdTOfGIyZBgAe1D6HzAoUABzDUFbEUcXKXdIbz8xHCkgshU4KEjouI0tFLA9CuMKiysYdBAEHFCQZCY4KgAVaggfAB4AaWR0z19-YABtBi0GAF0APgAKADc4THpnaMQwfuzgLkJyXvph3gWASk2XKB3+rcOCY-lkM4XpYOAYZFX1gDpyrogYwWOIOAwLh9gmQoBAwOgoG08tDoX80WtMDwUSiwhFGOpsch+MFeCNMD4UMjobD4YioYTSGi-hisQzSAUivjWSjiWR+LwgA)):

> Type 'Extract<MultiA, { type: K; }> & { foo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Extract<ExtB, { type: K; }>

Typescript tries to test with `MultiA` and `ExtB`, which would imply that it tests with`K = 'multi-a'` and `K = 'multi-b'` at the same time.

I guess the `Extract` type is insufficient here, as it is not being resolved early enough?
What is the alternative here?

Comment: This is a current limitation in TS; the compiler can't verify that any specific type is assignable to a generic conditional type; see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  Either you need to loosen your typing in the implementation (e.g., type assertion, single-call-signature overload, etc) or refactor to avoid such types.  See [this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Na1v0N) for those possibilities.  Does that address your question fully or am I missing something?

Comment: Fully answered, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler can't do the sort of higher order analysis needed to verify that a value is assignable to a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on an unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.

The type `Extract<Ext, { type: K }>` uses [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union), which is implemented as a conditional type.  And since `K` is a generic type parameter, the compiler is unable to see that `{...val, foo: ''}` or `{...val, bar: ''}` is assignable to it.  It cannot use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) in the `if`/`else` block to narrow `K` either.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) to provide some type safe and convenient way to implement a generic function returning a conditional type, but for now it's not possible.

---

One way to proceed is just accept that you know something the compiler doesn't and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell it that the return values are of type `Extract<Ext, {type: K}>`.  Equivalently you can use write your function is a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) which allows the implementation to be more loosely typed than the call signature:

```
// call signature
function mapTypes<K extends Multi['type']>(
    val: Extract<Multi, { type: K }>): Extract<Ext, { type: K }>;

// implementation
function mapTypes(val: { type: Multi['type'] }) {
    if (val.type === 'multi-a') {
        return {
            ...val,
            foo: '',
        }
    } else {
        return {
            ...val,
            bar: '',
        }
    }
}
```

So this version behaves how you'd like from the caller's side, and gives up a little compiler-guaranteed type safety inside the implementation.

---

Another approach you could take is to give up on conditional types like this and refactor to a version where the types produced are structurally equivalent to what you want, even if they are not displayed that way:

```
function mapTypes<K extends Multi['type']>(val: Extract<Multi, { type: K }>) {

    const k: K = val.type;

    const o = {
        "multi-a": { foo: "" },
        "multi-b": { bar: "" }
    }[k];


    return {
        ...val, ...o
    }
}
```

By doing a property lookup with a key of type `K` into an object with keys of type `Multi['type']`, the compiler represents this as a generic [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), and by spreading both `val` and this indexed access type together, the compiler represents this as an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).  Thus the return type of this version of `mapTypes()` is:

```
// Extract<Multi, { type: K; }> & { "multi-a": { foo: string; }; "multi-b": { bar: string; };}[K]
```

That's not pretty, but it turns out to be equivalent to your desired output type.  Indeed, the following lines compile with no error:

```
const extA: ExtA = mapTypes({ type: "multi-a" }); // okay
const extB: ExtB = mapTypes({ type: "multi-b" }); // okay
```

So this version is type safe both inside and outside the function, but the caller sees a less desirable return type.  We can't get the best of both worlds here, unfortunately... for the same reason as before, the compiler cannot tell that the ugly and pretty return types are equivalent *generically* for unspecified `K`; it only sees the equivalence when you specify `K` to be either `"multi-a"`, or `"multi-b"`.

---

Of course, it's up to you whether type safety is more or less important than call signature aesthetics!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIFcA2ZgEFkDeAUMqcmAJ4AOEAXMgOQC2WOAtHAwDREC+RoSLEQoM2YACFCJMpRr1mrYGwBG3PkTmilyALxol+AD4HxEgNxEB4aPCTIAogA8w+CC4ggAJgGdTOfGIyZBgAe1D6HzAoUABzDUFbEUcXKXdIbz8xHCkgshU4KEjouI0tFLA9CuMKiysQOCYIHypkgBlwn09pGVIAej7kBDhMTGQfYFiGsHQoCF6Q9BAEHFCQZCY4KgAVamaAHgBpZHTPX39gAG0GLQYAXQA+AAoF4IA3EfpnaMQwfezgFxCOQ9vRjrwHgBKL4uKC-fbfIEEEHyZDgh6WBYDZDAJhUTAQJrgOCrEALGBLFbANYbLa7Gg+J4fTD0ZFaegA663O7IXiQ6TBYLAGDIJkjAB05V00sYLHEHAY-LygsFcxmUHWypV2vFuuZPG1hpC4QU6iNZH4ht4J0wXQF5uQatmmteDt14v1rvNBSKjDNDst2sDpH4GiIDSaLWSACUIHYwKEoD1ghTlqTaTs9j4jicPJkLly9vdnsyYT8Vv8lEiUXQ0byocntQg1lFkABrMFVZmSvaYw3NkCt0JVLWGgBEcvYcDHrONEWQY7HvINDonSlUM+BPvoi95Xt5lzbdz72qdGvt5vd+uQ7tC++De+C2O+cIrAOr7LR5nryAAZMC13ladZzCecohiEBYm-Xhv0A9gVE3ZFt3GEpIOg8xeEuQ47isYIB1bdJcDLfB9E2TMGSeNlQQXSdlGnXlIUsPCW0qdIJDLKRSLpLNKJrHdaI3BjMV4IA)